# SetPasswordHashAsync unavailable in userstore which implements IUserPasswordStore

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a custom userstore and usermanager and successfully avoided using Entity Framework.

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> { }

public class CustomUserStore<T> : IUserStore<T>, IUserPasswordStore<T>, IQueryableUserStore<T>, IUserRoleStore<T>, IUserEmailStore<T>,   IUserLockoutStore<T, string>, IUserTwoFactorStore<T, string>, UserPhoneNumberStore<T>, IUserLoginStore<T> where T : ApplicationUser { }
```

The custom userstore contains many methods, including:

```
Task<string> IUserPasswordStore<T, string>.GetPasswordHashAsync(T user) {
  return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    return ((T)repository.GetUserByUserName(user.UserName)).PasswordHash; 
  });
}

Task IUserPasswordStore<T, string>.SetPasswordHashAsync(T user, string passwordHash) {
  if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
  user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Everything works perfectly with my identity implementation including email confirmations and password recovery with generated user tokens. When I try and call these 2 methods above from a controller which has the usermanager injected, I get an error:

Error   1   'mynamespace.CustomUserManager' does not contain a definition for 'SetPasswordHashAsync' and no extension method 'SetPasswordHashAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'mynamespace.CustomUserManager' could be found

The problem is that the userstore does indeed have a a definition for these 2 methods. If I comment them out, the custom userstore will not build. Why can the controller not see their definitions?

```
await customUserManager.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, hashedNewPassword); // build error
```

In the application I don't need to call these functions for normal activity. The problem is I'm migrating from AspnetMembership to AspNet.Identity and trying to automate password migration rather than require users to reset their passwords. It will be a one-off job if I can get it to work.

Comment: What happens if you implement the methods implicitly as opposed to explicitly?  The code above makes the methods only accessible when the object is explicitly cast to IUserPasswordStore<T, string>, perhaps whatever is trying to call your code is trying to call it on object that has not been explicitly cast.

Comment: Hi Mick: If I change the UserStore implementation from explicit to implicit it makes no difference to the compile error. If I leave it explicit and attempt to cast the usermanager using an interface reference:
((IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser, string>)customUserManager).SetPasswordHashAsync(user, hashedNewPassword);
This results in a runtime error, though it does compile:
Unable to cast object of type 'mynamespace.CustomUserManager' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserPasswordStore`2[mynamespace.ApplicationUser,System.String]'